# Adding port to zf2 http client uri

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to connect to `http://10.11.12.1:8083` so I use this code snippet:

```
public function tempAction(){
    $client = new Client();
    $client->setAdapter('Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl');
    $client->setUri('http://10.11.12.1:8083');
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $result                 = $client->send();
    $body                   = $result->getBody();
    Debug::dump("DEBUG: " . $body);
```

Anyway, the error message I got is: 'Error in cURL request: connect() timed out!'. I tried to connect to the website `http://10.11.12.1:8083` by browser and it worked - I was able to see the expected user interface. Moreover I was able to use the code snippet to connect to a website without an explicitely named port. I guess I need to change my way of adding the port to the url?

I am using ZendFramework 2.

Answer (score 0):

The way I found to add port is to use Zend\Uri\Uri

example

```
    $uri = new Uri();

    $uri->setHost($this->config['server']);
    $uri->setPort($this->config['port']);
    $uri->setPath('/jsonrpc');
```

Then in your client:

```
$client = new Client($uri->toString(), array());
```

There is probably a better way but that worked.